# Grails rendering pre-rendered JSON

Tags: json, grails, rendering

Leading up to this, I had problems rendering a collection of data, so started rendering each item in the collection and concatenating the strings. The problem is that the output pre-rendered JSON string has brackets ] changed to braces } and double quotes " changed to '.

JSON is changed from

```
{"root":{"delta":
```

to

```
['root':['delta':{'id':
```

This is despite the string definitely being in the first format.

The code to pre-render is:

```
def crConverter = cr as JSON
if (i < maxRecords) {
      delta += crConverter.toString() + ','
```

I can see the correct format of the string in the debugger just before it is output. Output is printed out in the controller as follows:

```
response.contentType = 'application/json'; 
try {
      response.outputStream <<  jsonString
```

Comment: What happens if you change `def crConverter` to `String crConverter` and remove the `toString()`?

Comment: Not sure it works - http://grails.org/Converters+Reference. Need a Converter, which gets toString() called on it. Also not sure I have actually found a problem. The output doesn't validate jsonlint.com and it doesn't look right - but our client groovy script can read it.